# Hybris accelerator electronics site always redirect to https

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am really new to hybris so I just installed the accelebrates followed the wiki page. But when I access the site using the http link

http://electronics.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/
it always redirect to 
https://electronics.local:9002/yacceleratorstorefront/electronics/en/

I have suspect the get and the server have return 302 Found with the new redirect URL.

Can anyone help to explain what is the settings and why hybris redirect me to https link like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the accelerator's default behavior to change it, update the file `spring-security-config.xml` under your store front extension :

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much @BenoitVanalderweireldt. It works !. You save me lots of time.

Comment: Hi @Benoit Vanalderweireldt, Just edit that security settings is not enough. I have followed the instruction on this wiki https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/8aef3efe8669101481a0ffe871a2f84c.html. The shop page working on http now but the problem I cannot add the product to cart. The ajax request return 403 forbidden ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by deleting every instance of

`<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />`

or simply the

`requires-channel="https"`

in the places where interceptor was a bit more complex in the same file `spring-security-config.xml` mentioned by Benoit.

Then, just restarted the platform(no compilation required).

This works but obviously at the cost of removing all https requirements so this should only be used for demonstration purposes.